# when would it be good to set object to null. (JSF).

Tags: java, jsf, null

I know assigning object to null is a code smell but in what case would assigning object to null be useful.

Example: in jsf if you null an object you clear out the previous value store in session.

Q. When would you set object to null?

Q. In jsf 1.2 is their a way to flush the memory (release them) in jsf without nulling the value (for example you have clearData that sets all fields to null once you leave the page).

Answer (score 1):

> in jsf if you null an object you clear out the previous value store in session

No you don't. You have to call an API to accomplish that.

> Q. When would you set object to null?

Almost never.

> Q. In jsf 1.2 is their a way to flush the memory (release them) in jsf without nulling the value (for example you have clearData that sets all fields to null once you leave the page).

No. The @PreDestroy method of an @ViewScoped bean is currently never called. This was due to a theory that there is no identifiable time to call it, but I believe they have finally found one and are incorporating it into a future release of JSF 2.

Comment: hmm so in this case nulling out the value is the only way to free memory in jsf.